# How can I model the crevasses in this low-poly sphere?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I've been trying to recreate the main grey sphere in this image:

[image]

My guess so far is that the approach should be to decimate an icosphere, then inset and scale down to make the crevasses. If that's the best approach, I can't figure out how how to get nice variability in the size of the faces.

Is my idea there right, and if so how can I achieve that geometry?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### The Cell Fracture add-on would be a good start.

(The Cell Fracture add-on comes with Blender, all you have to do, is activating it via Menu -> Edit -> Preferences -> Add-ons)

1. Create a sphere (icosphere or rounded cube work best) with a decent polycount.

[image: create icosphere with 5 subdivisions]

2. Initiate Cell Fracture via <kbd>F3</kbd> - Search - Cell Fracture.

   In the settings dialog under "Own Particles" - "Point Source",
   change the Source Limit to 50 and under "Recursive Shatter", change
   the Recursive Subdivision to "Big" and hit "OK".

[image: Cell Fracture Settings]

3. Hide the original sphere, then select all objects with "_cell" in
   their names.

   Go to the "Transform Options" dropdown menu and check "Locations".
   This will provide us with the option to "explode" the individual
   objects away from their origins, which in our case is the center of
   the original sphere.

[image: Transform Settings]

4. Hit <kbd>S</kbd> and scale the selected objects, until the desired
   gap size is reached.

[image: Scale Sphere Fragments]

5. You can then unhide the original sphere and proceed from there with
   additional modifications (decimate, boolean, etc)

[image: After Scaling and Basic Material Setup]

[image: With Decimate Modifier on all Fragments]